# Regular expression issue in python

Tags: python

Why infinite wildcard (*) in the regular expression is treated differently in python? Please tell me **why in case one I'm getting different output than case two**?

**CASE ONE:**

```
import re
b= None
a=None
while a!='chk':
    a=input()
    b= re.findall('[A-Z][a-z]{1,400}',a)
    if b!=None:
        print(b,bool(b),type(b))
    if a=='chk':
            break

output:

CAPITALLETTERSsmallletters
['Ssmallletters'] True <class 'list'>
```

**CASE TWO:**

```
import re
b= None
a=None
while a!='chk':
    a=input()
    b= re.findall('[A-Z][a-z]*',a)
    if b!=None:
        print(b,bool(b),type(b))
    if a=='chk':
            break

output:

CAPITALLETTERSsmallletters
['C', 'A', 'P', 'I', 'T', 'A', 'L', 'L', 'E', 'T', 'T', 'E', 'R', 'Ssmallletters'] True <class 'list'>
```

Comment: `*` means “zero or more”. `{1,400}` is “1 to 400”. Did you mean `+`, “one or more”?

Comment: What the string do you input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CASE ONE:**
The regular expression says:
*Look for things that have a uppercase letter followed by 1 to 400 lowercase letters*
This gives one hit, the one it prints.

**CASE TWO:**
The regular expression says:
*Look for things that have one uppercase letter followed by **0** to infinite lowercase letters*
In this case each capital letter alone is one hit, plus the same hit you had before.